# What is the correct pronunciation of "February"?

Tags: pronunciation

Please tell how do we correctly pronounce the word *February*. Though common pronunciation should be *Feb-RU-ary*, in some dictionaries it is *Feb-U-ary* where the first "r" is dropped. Which one is correct?

Comment: Lots of words have silent letters. Do you have some special reason to believe that the dictionaries you have consulted might be mistaken?

Comment: There is no 'correct' pronunciation of anything.

Comment: Lots of people drop the first R.  To many people's ears, this makes them sound uneducated.  If you are learning English, you would be well advised to pronounce both of the Rs.

Comment: @DavidWallace: interesting take.  In the US, at least, the silent "R" pronunciation is extensive, to the point where I don't think it sounds uneducated here.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: there may not be a single 'correct' way to pronounce anything (except maybe ˈɛnɪˌθɪŋ), but there are several 'incorrect' ways. (For example, I wouldn't pronounce _February_ as "MARCH".)

Comment: One is 'supposed' to say it with '-RU-', but people hardly ever do (except maybe newscasters). And really, it's kinda hard to tell which one someone is using in natural flowing speech. 'Liberry' for 'library', on the other hand, is pretty obviously 'wrong'.

Comment: I remember long ago, when Walter Cronkite did the CBS evening news, probably in the 1960s, he put a little postscript at the end of his broadcast one day. A newly-revised dictionary had listed the "you" pronunciation of February along with the usual pronunciation. He (W. C.) had never liked the "correct" pronunciation with R, so from now on (with the dictionary's authority) he intended to use the "you" pronunciation.

Comment: @Mitch Maybe *you* are "supposed to" but I'm not. As far as I know there is nobody enforcing this rule, and it is honored largely in the breach.

Comment: @Mitch Everyone in my family, and perhaps also from my region, has always said the *r* in *February*. But I come from a family of educators with careful diction in the Inland North, so this may have influenced it.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Oh, my parents and grandparents certainly enforced the rule. We weren’t supposed to sound like we were uneddicated.

Comment: I see! Evidently February is pronounced "Shibboleth" ;)

Answer (score 8):

This question could be much improved if you gave specific mention of the dictionaries you've checked.

My Mac's online dictionary clearly shows both pronunciations are acceptable:

[image]

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/february) lists both pronunciations of both as well, and you can hear them both, if you [visit there](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/february), and click on the two speaker icons:

[image]

Click on the speaker icon at [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/February?r=66), and you will hear both pronunciations, separated by an "or":

[image]

With so many reputable sources listing both pronunciations as valid, the word could be pronounced either way.  If you manage to find a dictionary that only lists one pronunciation (such as [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/february)), that would indicate some abridgement.

For the record, here's how the OED lists it (both with a silent *r*, and an enunciated *r*):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You already know that there is no "correct" pronunciation. The Longman Pronunciation Dictionary (2008) gives **seven** variants used in British English and **two** variants used in American English.

As for the word "February", **it's a famous example of the divide between BrE and AmE**. The most common pronunciation in BrE is with "ru" and in AmE it's with "ju". According to a poll conducted by Professor Wells, the variant with "ju" is becoming more common with the younger generation in Britain; cf. "Feb-yoo-" is now becoming the accepted standard (Oxford Dictionaries Online).